# How do I use columns from a joined table in a match against clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am writing a business directory and I use MySQL to store the data.  I have three tables that I would like to use in this scenario:  listings, regions, and categories.  Listings have titles and descriptions.  Regions and categories both have titles.  I would like to create a search feature that would allow users to combine keywords of listing titles and descriptions with category and region titles.  For example, if someone searches the string "cheesecake in pennsylvania" they would get a result for The Cheesecake Factory in Philly.  Can I do this with MATCH(columns) AGAINST(keywords)?

The MySQL query below is currently returning the error Incorrect arguments to MATCH

```
SELECT
    l.listing_id AS id, l.category_id, l.title AS listing_title, l.description, l.address, l.city, l.zip, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(l.date_submitted) AS date_submitted, l.latitude, l.longitude,
    ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(40.293861) ) * cos( radians( l.latitude) ) * cos( radians( l.longitude ) - radians(-76.600252) ) + sin( radians(40.293861) ) * sin( radians( l.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance,
    c.category_id AS cat_id, c.title AS cat_title, c.slug AS cat_slug, 
    r.region_id AS region_id, r.title AS region_title, r.slug AS region_slug 
FROM listings AS l
LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON l.category_id = c.category_id 
LEFT JOIN regions AS r ON l.region_id = r.region_id 
WHERE MATCH (l.title,l.description,l.city,r.title,c.title) AGAINST ('cheesecake in pennsylvania')
```

If I remove r.title and c.title from the match columns it works fine.  Here is a [SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89719/1)to further demonstrate.  I am also open to other ideas for doing this a better way other than using match.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. The columns named in `MATCH()` must be part of a single fulltext index, but you can't define a single fulltext index across multiple tables.

You may need to combine three `MATCH()` clauses with `OR` (Like i did in your example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89719/11).

Answer (score 0):

you need to have text indexes.

You First alter table and execute Sql Query like this

```
alter table listings add fulltext index_text(title);
alter table listings add fulltext index_text(description);
alter table listings add fulltext index_text(city);

alter table categories add fulltext index_text(title);
alter table regions add fulltext index_text(title);
```

and Query Run now

```
SELECT
l.listing_id AS id, l.category_id, l.title AS listing_title, l.description, l.address, l.city, l.zip, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(l.date_submitted) AS date_submitted, l.latitude, l.longitude,
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(40.293861) ) * cos( radians( l.latitude) ) * cos( radians( l.longitude ) - radians(-76.600252) ) + sin( radians(40.293861) ) * sin( radians( l.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance,
c.category_id AS cat_id, c.title AS cat_title, c.slug AS cat_slug, 
r.region_id AS region_id, r.title AS region_title, r.slug AS region_slug 
FROM listings AS l
LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON l.category_id = c.category_id 
LEFT JOIN regions AS r ON l.region_id = r.region_id 
WHERE MATCH (l.title,l.description,l.city,r.title,c.title) AGAINST `('cheesecake in pennsylvania')`
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you have written seems to be working except you can't pass arguments to match from multiple table.
if you remove last 2 arguments from your query it is working perfectly